# VMware workstation occasionaly can't use all my physically memory?

Tags: memory, vmware-workstation

My VMware workstation occasionally gives me "not enough physical memory available to start this VM" when  I have 2-3GB assigned to my VM and in my preferences I have 6GB ram for all my VMs and my total physical RAM is 8GB. It worked before but the VM occasionally freezes or so and now it gives me this error!? When I reduce the memory I can start my VM but I is this a common error? My memory works fine!?

Comment: Are you sure your not overstepping into your host OS ram too much? Leaving just 2GB for the host OS is a pretty small amount.

Comment: I suspect it's some error with VMware. It works before and 6GB is the maximum the VMWare tool allows me, so no. I don't think it's the problem!

Comment: Windows is usually meant to empower and not to restrict. As such you could very well do something you shouldn't but that does not justify it as a viable action. Likewise, just because it has worked, doesn't mean it should have worked or even let you do it. If you exit VMWare, how much memory is your OS using? The error implies that you are attempting to use more physical memory than you should be using.

Comment: With VLC and my browser W uses 24% from my 8GB, its about 6GB free!?

Comment: The amount VMware allows is configurable, so that’s not a good indicator.

Comment: @Phpdna: Well my point is that you're cutting it too close. You should leave 1-2GB of buffer space for the host.

Comment: @DanielB and Enigma his issue is caused by a bug in vmware, which is now fixed.

Comment: That might be true. It’s still totally possible for a VM to fail if other programs hog RAM and (especially) virtual memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in [Version 10.0.3 under Windows 8.1](http://blogs.vmware.com/workstation/2014/10/workstation-10-issue-recent-microsoft-windows-8-1-update.html) after installing the october update rollup for Windows 8.1. The [issue is fixed](http://blogs.vmware.com/workstation/2014/10/vmware-workstation-10-player-6-update-now-available.html) in [Version 10.0.4](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws10/doc/workstation-1004-release-notes.html).